# Get images from Firebase Firestore and add them to an "li"

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I've tried to retrieve images from Firebase Storage and then add them to an "li"-tag which is a post. But I get src=undefined when running the code below. The divs in the "li"-tag works. Anyone that can help me?

Why am I getting the error: cannot read property 'get' of undefined?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="posts">
   </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var postDocRef = db.collection('posts').doc(uid).collection('userPosts')

postDocRef.get().then(snapshot => {
setupPosts(snapshot.docs)
})

const posts = document.querySelector('.posts');

const setupPosts = (data) => {

    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {

        var docRefIDpost = docRef.id

        const post = doc.data();
        const li = `
        <li>
            <div class="title">${post.title}</div>
            <div class="content">${post.content}</div>
            <img class="img">
        </li>
        `;

        var imgRef = db.collection("posts").doc(uid).collection('userPosts').doc(docRefIDpost);

        imgRef.get().then(function(snapshot) {
            var picURL = snapshot.get("picURL")
            
                    var imgpost = document.querySelector(".img");
        
                    imgpost.src = picURL
        
            })

        


        html += li
    })

    posts.innerHTML = html;

}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's each `userPosts` document structured? Have you checked that `imgRef` `snapshot` is not empty?
I believe the actual issue might be that you're missing a call to `data()` when accessing `imageURL`:

```
var picURL = snapshot.data().picURL
```

Comment: Still no change. But now, I'm getting an error in the console: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined. The snapshot is not empty, because I get the snapshot logged in the console.

Comment: I guess it is the .get() function which is the problem.

Comment: Yes, the get() function is the problem.The object returned from `data()` is a js object – you can access `picURL` and other properties directly. I've adjusted my answer above.